# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array when looping over regular array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access some kind of dynamic key inside of my PHP `foreach` loop, I'm looping over an array of objects where each `$item` is a single object containing several key/value pairs, one of the keys is called `event_count` whilst another is called `created_at`.

However, I don't want to hardcode these keys as the user has control over what they want to see, thus I'm pulling through the key that they wish to look at, and it's here where I'm getting this error.

```php
public function getStructure($type, $data, $labelsKey, $dataKey)
  {
      switch ($type) {
        case 'chart':
            $chart = [
              'labels' => [],
              'data' => []
            ];

            foreach ($data as $key => $item) {

              // TODO: can't use $labelsKey or $dataKey for $item for some reason??
              array_push($chart['labels'], $item[$labelsKey]);
              array_push($chart['data'], $item[$dataKey]);

            }

            return [
              'chart' => $chart
            ];
            break;
      }
  }
```

`$labelsKey` in this context contains a string called 'created_at`, whilst` $dataKey` contains 'event_count'.

What am I doing wrong?

If I change `$item[$labelsKey]` to `$item->created_at` then it works as expected, but this doesn't meet my requirement, would it be a simple case of setting `$item->$labelsKey`?

Comment: `stdClass` uses Object Notation `->property` instead of Array Access `['property']`, so `$item->{$labelsKey}` is valid syntax, and is similar to `$item[$labelsKey]`.

Comment: Sidenote, in Laravel, if you're using Models to get your data (`User::get()`) instead of something like `DB::table('users')->get()`, then your code will work as written. Models are hybrid arrays/objects, meaning `$model->property` and `$model['property']` both work. (I'm assuming your `$data` is the result of a database call due to `created_at` and `events_counts` indicating database columns/aggregates)